# Spanish form field labels in DevDemon's Forms?

Tags: forms, multi-language

Is there a way to translate the form fields for devdemon's Forms (default Form Tools and Powertools label fields) in spanish? Has anyone done this before>

Answer (score 2):

It's not covered in the docs, but apparently, according to [this forum post](https://www.devdemon.com/forums/viewthread/1921/), there are language packs for the forms module to allow you to do this, yes. I'd check in with the DevDemon folks to find out which languages are available and how to go about loading the language pack.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted DevDemon and the answer is:

You need to copy the english folder to a folder called spanish, then change
all the text in the file to Spanish.